# Show that for any real number $c$ there is exactly one integer in the interval $I=(c,c+1]$.

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers, integers

> Show that for any real number c there is exactly one integer in the interval $I = (c, c+1]$.

---

First, I think I need to define a set $S=\{x\vert x\in\mathbb{Z},x \leq c+1 \}$.

Suppose $c+1\geq 0$, then $0$ is a member of $S$. If $c+1<0$, by Archimedean Property, there exists a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>-(c+1)\rightarrow c+1>-n$; thus the set $S$ is not empty. Because $c+1$ is an upper bound of $S$, so $S$ is bounded above, set $S$ has a maximum $m$ where $m\leq c+1$; by the definition of $S$, $m\in S$

To show $m$ is an unique number, assume there is an integer $m'\in I$ where $m'>m>c\rightarrow m'-m>c>0\rightarrow 0<m'-m<c+1-c=1$. Since there is no integers between $1$ and $0$, this brings a contradiction; hence there is a unique integer in $I$.

---

For the argument I wrote, I don't feel that is right. In the first part, I think I need to show more detail on why $m\in S$. In part $2$, I am so good at inequality, I am not sure it is right or not.

Could someone check my argument? if the argument is not right, please give me a hit or a suggestion that I can rewrite a better argument. Thanks.

Comment: $S$ should be the set of numbers $x\le c+1$, not $x<c+1$.

Comment: @QuangHoang Right, thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to explain a little why $m\in S$ (if not, then $m\le c$). In that direction, why $0\le c+1$? I think you could start, instead of $0\le c+1$, pick any $n\le c+1$. If $ n\not\in S$, then there's a maximum $m\le c+1$, which is in $S$. The unique part looks OK.

Answer (score -2):

Notice that
$c < x ≤ c + 1$
if and only if
$−c − 1 ≤ −x < −c$.
Since there is exactly one integer $n$ in the interval $[−c − 1, −c)$, $−n$ is the unique integer in the interval $(c, c + 1]$.